# Union clause in Google Visualization Query Language

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization, google-query-language

I need to create a single `datatable` pulling datas from different sheets of a Google Spreadsheet, is there a way to emulate in `Google Visualization API Language` the `union` clause provided by SQL?

[Google Query Language documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#language-clauses) shows there's no `union` avaliable and actually this sounds reasonable because changing sheet the part affected is the address (different gid) not the query statement.

Comment: see the [join()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#join) method

Comment: thank you really much WhiteHat, i was blind to not see that one :-).
i'll give it a try immediately

Answer (score 1):

One way to emulate the SQL UNION clause is to append the different source ranges by using the array handling features of Google Sheets.

Example:

Assume that there are two ranges to put together as a single array, Sheet1!A1:B10 and Sheet2!A5:B25. Then write the following formula in the cell A1 of new sheet

```
={Sheet1!A1:B10;Sheet2!A5:B25}
```

For further details checkout [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)